# Why consume() on a KeyEvent in an event filter not working?

Tags: events, javafx, consuming

I want to filter some characters i.e. the letter "a" in a TextField. I explicitly don't want to use the recommended **TextFormatter / setTextFormatter()** for this task.

The code sample below should actually consume the event on the event-dispatching chain before it arrives to the TextField node, which is a child node of **parentNode**, but it doesn't. Same happens if I set the filter on the textfield node itself of course.

Why?

```
    parentNode.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: _ I explicitly don't want to use the recommended TextFormatter_ why not?

Comment: cause i want to understand event processing lol, thats why. Using TextFormatter is easy in this example but not the issue ...

Comment: ahh, I see, but then your answer doesn't really help you (in fully understanding the event processing :) Anyway, you should edit your question: academic excercises are perfectly valid but if a question is about them, it should be stated clearly in the question

Comment: thats why I wrote "understand event processing" and NOT "fully". Reading questions/ comments thoroughly prevents unnecessary discussions ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ah, really strange, seems like **KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED** is not sufficient to handle all dispatched events.
If I use the more generic **KeyEvent.ANY** instead the following code works:

```
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> {
        if (event.getCharacter().matches("[aA]"))
            event.consume();
    });
```

Comment: you don't need `ANY` but the type that generates input, that is represents a char ;)

Comment: give me code example please, so I can see what you mean ,thx.

Comment: Text input controls use `KEY_TYPED` for character input, since that's the only event type where [`getCharacter()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter()) returns something meaningful. Though it uses `KEY_PRESSED` for other key events, such as backspace, enter, arrow keys, and so on. You can see the event handling code in the internal behavior class: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/TextInputControlBehavior.java#L107